# group by in sas

Tags: sas

I've the below dataset as input

```
ID  
--  

1  
2  
2  
3  
4  
4  
4  
5
```

And need a new dataset as below

```
ID   count of ID  
--   -----------

1    1  
2    2  
3    1  
4    3  
5    1
```

Could you please tell how to do this in SAS wihtout using PROC SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DATA Have; 
 input id ; 
 datalines;
 1
 2
 2
 3
 4
 4
 4
 5 
 ;

Proc Sort data=Have;
 by ID;
run;

Data Want;
 Set Have;
 By ID;
 If first.ID then Count=0;
 Count+1;
 If Last.ID then Output;
Run;
```

Comment: Many THanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I've started to learn SAS dats y my ques is so simple

Answer (score 7):

or how about Proc Freq or Proc Summary?  These avoid having to presort the data.

```
proc freq data=have noprint;
table id / out=want1 (drop=percent);
run;

proc summary data=have nway;
class id;
output out=want2 (drop=_type_);
run;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
proc sql noprint;
create table test as select distinct id, count(id)
from your_table
group by ID
order by ID
;
quit;
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to do without using PROC SQL??

Comment: Just curious -- why not use SQL?

Comment: Hi,
You can avoid sql by using a data step like Carolina.

Comment: I like the power of sql!

Answer (score 0):

```
PROC SORT DATA=YOURS NOPRINT;
  BY ID; RUN;
PROC MEANS DATA=YOURS;
  VAR ID;
  BY ID;
OUTPUT OUT=NEWDATASET N=; RUN;
```

You can also choose to keep only the Id and *N* variables in your newdataset.

Answer (score 0):

We can use simple PROC SQL count to do this:

```
 proc sql;
 create table want as
    select id, count(id) as count_of_id 
    from have
    group by id;
 quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another possibility, often known as a DoW construction:

```
Data want;
  do count=1 by 1 until(last.ID);
    set have;
    by id;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score -1):

If the aggregation you want to do is complex then go with PROC SQL only as we are more familiar with Group by in SQL

```
proc sql ;
create table solution_1 as select distinct ID, count(ID)
from table_1
group by ID
order by ID
;
quit;
```

OR

- If you are using SAS- EG Query builders are very useful in small
  analyses .

It's just drag & drop the columns u want to aggregate and in summary option Select whatever operation you want to perform like Avg,Count,miss,NMiss etc .

Comment: Of course, First, take a deep look at the question:  `how to do this in SAS **without using PROC SQL?**` Second, you have duplicated the 3rd answer.