# Calculating Frequency of Defaults in a given Bucketed Score

Tags: sas

I have a table with Scores and default indicator values.
I sorted the table on the basis of descending scores and then applied proc rank to populate the group column.
Below is a sample of the dataset after the proc rank step.

```
                            Obs    Scores    Def     group

                              1      100      0        9
                              2      100      1        9
                              3       99      0        9
                              4       97      0        9
                              5       97      0        9
                              6       95      0        9
                              7       94      0        9
                              8       92      0        9
                              9       92      0        9
                             10       91      0        9
                             11       91      0        9
                             12       89      1        8
                             13       88      0        8
                             14       87      0        8
                             15       87      0        8
                             16       86      0        8
                             17       85      0        8
                             18       84      0        8
                             19       84      0        8
                             20       83      0        8
                             21       83      0        8
                             22       83      0        8
                             23       82      0        8
                             24       81      0        7
                             25       80      0        7
                             26       80      1        7
```

I want to count the population(i.e. number of scores that lie within each group).
Also count the number of defaults in each group.
I tried the below code:

```
proc rank data = sortedScore groups = 10 out = Score_sorted_10;
    var Scores ;
    ranks Scores_group;
run;

data NumCount;
set Score_sorted_10;
Retain Popnum 0;
Retain Badnum 0;
do i=0 to 9;
if Scores_group=i
then Popnum=sum(Popnum,1);
if Scores_group=i and Def=1
then Badnum=sum(Def,1);
end;
```

But this code is getting into infinite loop.
Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [group by in sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352346/group-by-in-sas)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to do it using proc sql.
The following query will do the trick:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select distinct 
    Group,
    count(scores) as Nbr_Scores,
    sum(def) as Nbr_Def
from have
group by group;
quit;
```